# sparklyr: fill `spark_read_parquet path` argument from list

Tags: r, apache-spark, amazon-s3, sparkr, sparklyr

I'd like to process several files in the same s3 bucket in the same way. So, I created a list of the filenames:

```
dt <- seq(as.Date("1991/12/23"), by = "day", length.out = 5)
dt_ls <- paste0('s3://donuts/date=',dt)
```

And then I run a for loop over that list:

```
for (i in 1:length(dt)){
  df <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "df", path = dt_ls[i]) #readin
  df_tbl <- tbl(sc, "df")                             #convert to tbl
  #perform w/e operations you like
  rm(df)
}
```

However, I immediately get one of two errors when trying to assign `path = dt_ls[i]`.

```
Error in UseMethod("invoke"): no applicable method for 'invoke' applied to an object of class "character"
```

or:

```
Error in as.vector(x, "character"): cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'
```

I see the same errors when running a single line in isolation, e.g.:

```
tmp <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "tmp", path = dt_ls[1])
```

My read of these errors is that I cannot pass an s3 filepath saved as an object to `spark_read_parquet`, because since the back end of the command is calling on `invoke` it doesn't direct to the contents of the list index I've passed to it. Therefore, I have to write the path directly into the `path` argument.

Is that a correct interpretation? Is there a work around so I can automate the opening of all these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The quotation marks that appear around a chr object in a list appear to have been the problem. Removing those quotation marks when passing a list index to the `path` argument in `spark_read_parquet` allows the function to run normally.

So the solution in brief:

`tmp <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "tmp", path = noquotes(dt_ls[1]))`

And an example of the input causing the issue:

```
   [1] “s3://donuts/date=2021-12-23”
   [2] “s3://donuts/date=2021-12-24”
   [3] “s3://donuts/date=2021-12-25”
```

So the filepath passed must resemble:

`[1] s3://donuts/date=2021-12-23`